# Dropdown box appearing incorrectly on GitHub Pages built with Jekyll

Tags: html, css, jekyll, github-pages

My GitHub Pages site built using Jekyll is not showing my navbar correctly when pushed to GitHub. When built locally using 'jekyll serve' it functions correctly as shown:

[image: Correct Navbar]

However when pushed to github the title is not visible and it seems the links are displayed above the dropdown boxes:

[image: Incorrect Navbar]

Locally I have Jekyll 3.4.3 which is the same as listed on github, and previously my site displayed normally (the same locally as online) but after a few months hiatus I can't seem to get it to display correctly again. I'm not very experienced with Jekyll as this is my first experiment with it but I do have some other web development experience.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

navbar.html

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
<!--            <form class="navbar-search pull-right" 
action="http://google.com/search" method="get">
{% if site.safe %}
            <input type="hidden" name="q" value="site:{{ site.url | remove_first:'http://' }}">
{% else %}
            <input type="hidden" name="q" value="site:{{ site.url | domain_name }}">
{% endif %}
            <input type="text" name="q" class="input-medium search-query" placeholder="Search">
        </form> -->
        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
{% for node in site.navbar_list %}
{% if node.name == page.group %}{% assign active = 'active' %}
{% else %}{% assign active = nil %}{% endif %}
{% if node.dropdown %}
                <li class="dropdown dropdown-container {{ active }}">
                    <a class="dropdown-link" href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ node.link }}">{{ node.name }}</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">{{ node.name }}<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    {% for sub in node.dropdown %}
                        <li><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ sub.link }}">{{ sub.name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </li>
{% else %}
                <li class="{{ active }}">
                    <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ node.link }}">{{ node.name }}</a>
                </li>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Style.css

```
/* title of the site */
#header {
    height: 80px;
}
#header hgroup {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 20px;
}
#header h1 {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1.75em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#header h2 {
    color: #ccc;
    margin: 0 0 4px 16px;
    line-height: 0.8;
    font-size: 1.0em;
    font-weight: normal;
}
#header a,
#header a:hover,
#header a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* header.html: navbar */
.navbar-fixed-top {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: static;
}
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-inner {
    padding: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.067);
}
.navbar .nav > .active > a,
.navbar .nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar .nav > .active > a:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
}
.navbar .btn-navbar {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.lt-ie9 .collapse {
    overflow: visible; /* removed from 2.1.1, but still IE need this */
}

/* header.html: dropdown container */
.navbar .nav > li.dropdown-container {
    position: relative !important;
}
.navbar .nav > li.dropdown-container .dropdown-link {
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.navbar .nav > li.dropdown-container .caret {
    margin-left: 1.5em;
}
.navbar .nav > li.dropdown-container .dropdown-link + .dropdown-toggle {
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: can you try ditching the protocol-agnostic hrefs `//...min.css` and using `https://...min.css`

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know what you mean, site.baseurl is defined with http:// but I didn't include that in my post because as far as I can see the links work fine. Is there another location I should be including this to fix my problem?

Comment: I meant how about converting links like `//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/2.3.2/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css` into **`https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/2.3.2/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css`**?

Comment: Thankyou, but I still don't know where I am to make this change - can you give me an example from my code? Or a location it's likely to be in my repo?

Comment: `_includes/head.html`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I've updated those links and looked for other instances where I might need to change this but I've still got the same issue.

Comment: It looks like those changes don't matter. You may undo them if you want

Comment: Main problem is that you are using the wrong dependencies, comment everything in your Gemfile and just use `github-pages`. Then work from there and everything you do locally will be reflected online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your problem you need to copy `style.css` file from `_includes\css` to `assets\css` and rename it to `site.css` (because you already have `style.css` in `assets\css` folder) then you have to add link to `_includes\head.html` as below:

```
{% endcase %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/css/site.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/css/style.css">

<!-- Font Awesome -->
```

Comment: Thank you! I just want to note for others who may also have this issue: I previously tried this by _cutting_ and pasting but my site would not build locally, but _copying_ allowed my site to build locally and now is fixed on GitHub.
Thanks again!